# How to access the XML object?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have this API call and based on it and on the data that gets filled.
I want to be able to access the models parameters and use them in my parent widget.

```
static Future<CustomerPhotoMeter?> photoMeter(
  var _response, String methodName) async {
try {
  String str = _response.toString();
  var invo = xml.XmlDocument.parse(str);
  var elements = invo.findAllElements("dtCUST");
  if (elements.isEmpty) {
    return null;
  }
  String MTR_CITY = '',CTYM_NAME = '', MTR_NUM = '';

  return elements.map((e) {
    try {
      MTR_CITY = e.findElements('MTR_CITY').first.text;
    } catch (ex) {
      MTR_CITY = "";
    }

    try {
      CTYM_NAME = e.findElements('CTYM_NAME').first.text;
    } catch (ex) {
      CTYM_NAME = "";
    }

    try {
      MTR_NUM = e.findElements('MTR_NUM').first.text;
    } catch (ex) {
      MTR_NUM = "";
    }

    return CustomerPhotoMeter(
        MTR_CITY ,CTYM_NAME, MTR_NUM);
  }).single;
} on Exception catch (_) {
  return null;
 }
 }
```

and this is how I defined it in my parent screen

```
late CustomerPhotoMeter ?PhotoMeter;
```

> but I get the photoMeter hasn't been initialized.

This is how I'm doing it the widget is a custom card.

```
CustomerInfoCard(mtrCity: PhotoMeter!.MTR_CITY, ctymName: PhotoMeter!.CTYM_NAME, mtrNum: 
PhotoMeter!.MTR_NUM,onTap: () {  },)
```

here is where I'm calling it and the values in the photo meter that gets returned. they are used in another api call but that isn't relevant since I need that data in my custom card.

```
).then(
      (value) => api_connect.photoMeter(value, methodName).then((value) => {
            // Navigator.pop(context),
            if (value != null)
              {
                setState(() {
                  PhotoMeter = value;
                }),
                invoiceInfo(PhotoMeter!.MTR_CITY, PhotoMeter!.MTR_NUM),
              }
            else
              {
                showInfoDialog(context, "Error getting info"),
                Navigator.pop(context),

 backgroundColor: Colors.white, textColor: Colors.grey.shade900,),
              }
          })
```